# Record signal in AudioKit to file

Tags: ios, wav, audio-recording, microphone, audiokit

How can you record audio to a file in an app's documents directory using [AudioKit](http://audiokit.io/). They include examples on how to display live microphone signals and how to playback audio that's shipped as part of a binary but there is no information as far as I can tell regarding saving microphone input to a file.

I have managed to record files using `AKManager.sharedManager().startRecordingToURL(pathURL)` however when I export the file I get a silent .wav file. Am I not specifying a recording device?

I'm using Swift so answers in swift are preferable to Obj-C answers.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If so, could you please share how you solved it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Show some codes.

Answer (score -4):

In general AudioKit doesn't care whether the audio source is a series of pre-recorded files, a physical model, an oscillator, or a microphone.  Each of these can be processed and then the output is saved.

Comment: Aurelius, it'd be great if we could get an example of how to record audio from the microphone and save it to a file. Even though we know it's technically possible with AudioKit, there isn't any documentation for beginners specifying how to record and play back microphone input. In contrast, it's really obvious how to do this with AVFoundation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/

Comment: Working on this for the next version, late December/early January.